# What is the proj4string of the Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection?

Tags: r, epsg

Shapefiles of European data are available on the [Eurostat website](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units). I have loaded the `NUTS_2013_60M_SH` Shapefile in R with the command;

```
europeRG <- readOGR(dsn = patheurope, layer = "NUTS_RG_60M_2013", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have managed to transform the map of Europe to the [web mercator projection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) used by  OpenStreetMap and Google maps (EPSG:3857).

```
europewmercator <- spTransform(europeRG, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))
plot(europewmercator)
```

But a 2001 JRC and EuroGeographics document entitled [Map projections for Europe](http://www.ec-gis.org/sdi/publist/pdfs/annoni-etal2003eur.pdf) recommends using the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection:

> [...] Based on the above, it is documented that the projection to be used for statistical mapping in the EU, is the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection.
>   The projection center should be positioned at 9° E and 53° N. [...]

Wikipedia page of the [Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection#See_also). 
[This site](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/lambert_azimuthal_equal_area.html) says the epsg code of the "Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area" projection is 9820.
Unfortunately EPSG code 9820 is not available on https://epsg.io/?q=9820 or http://spatialreference.org 
but it is available on http://www.epsg-registry.org/
The issue is that the R function `sptransform()` doesn't recognise epsg:9820.

```
plot(europeRG)
# Transform To Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection
europeLAEA <- spTransform(europeRG, CRS("+init=epsg:9820"))

Error in spTransform(europeRG, CRS("+init=epsg:9820")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function 'spTransform': Error in CRS("+init=epsg:9820") : no options found in 'init' file
```

What proj4string could I use to perform the conversion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`9820` is the EPSG code for the laea projection **definition**. You can find it at https://www.epsg-registry.org/ under `retrieve by code`. This code numer has nothing to do with the commonly used EPSG codes like 4326 and 3857. These include projection **parameters** specified for a certain country or region.

For laea centered on Europe, the code is EPSG:3035, with these parameters:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

As you can see, the center is at 10°E and 52°N, which is not exactly what your source recommends. If you want those, you can build a custom CRS with parameters:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=53 +lon_0=9 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The x_0 and y_0 have no effect on the projection, they just shift the coordinates to avoid negative coordinates.

Comment: The appendix of Map Projections for Europe does list 10°E and 52°N so I think the 9,53 may be from one of the other chapters, not the "official" definition.

Comment: I have managed to transform the map to a custom CRS with parameters `"+proj=laea +lat_0=53 +lon_0=9"`. Thank you AndreJ for the explanation of x_0 and y_0 parameters. I had wondered about these 2 parameters in my notes, it's as if you read my mind.

Comment: @mkennedy that's right, pages 124-125 of the "[Map Projections for Europe](http://www.ec-gis.org/sdi/publist/pdfs/annoni-etal2003eur.pdf)" report give a description of ETRS-LAEA with "latitude of origin 52° N" and "longitude of origin 10° E". I'm wondering why this is inconsistent with the recommendations p55 of the same report and which projection centre I should use.

Comment: The difference of one degree is not very significant for a map of whole Europe. You just have to keep it in mind if you have to compare with other statistical map data that might use the other center point.

Comment: @PaulRougieux The chapters are papers presented at a workshop. I believe the annexes are the recommendations that came out of the workshop.

Answer (score 3):

The EPSG code for [LAEA](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-1/about-the-eea-reference-grid/eea_reference_grid_v1.pdf/at_download/file) is 3035. Further details available [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/)

Comment: Thanks [the European Environment Agency recommendation](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-1/about-the-eea-reference-grid/eea_reference_grid_v1.pdf/at_download/file) you linked-to mentions: "The coordinate reference system (CRS) is ETRS89-LAEA Europe, also known [..] under the identifier: EPSG:3035,[...] centred at 10°E, 52°N.". This helps me choose between the 2 options for a centre (see comments in the question above). Specifying the reference system with an EPSG code would certainly make projection easier.